# TypeError: Unsupported operand types for str and int

Tags: python

I`m trying out python code to train and test data for recommendation system when it showed TypeError: unspooerted operand type.

```
#creating user_job matrices for trainning and testing
train_data_matrix=np.zeros((n_users,n_jobs))
for line in train_data.itertuples():
   # print(n_users)
   train_data_matrix[line[1]-1,line[2]-1]=line[3]
print(train_data_matrix
```

.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-112-8bf50ecb6b71> in <module>
      3 for line in train_data.itertuples():
      4    # print(n_users)
----> 5    train_data_matrix[line[1]-1,line[2]-1]=line[3]
      6 print(train_data_matrix)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

Please help me solve this problem

Comment: error shows you where is problem so use `print(...)` and `print(type(...))` to check what you have in variables in this line. It seems you have strings and you try to subtract integer from string - like `"1" - 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `int` to convert string into integer.

```
#creating user_job matrices for trainning and testing
train_data_matrix=np.zeros((n_users,n_jobs))
for line in train_data.itertuples():
   # print(n_users)
   train_data_matrix[int(line[1])-1,int(line[2])-1]=int(line[3])
print(train_data_matrix)
```

`line[1]` is of `str` type, this is the reason you are getting error. check the type of `line[1]` by `print(type(line[1]))`.